# Moving columns with arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, show-hide

I want to make hide/show columns in HTML tables with arrows in header to move data.

Pressing arrow left will show left hidden column (ex. 2011-04 month column) and hide right column (ex. 2011-11 month column) and so on.
Is some kind of jQuery script for this, or do I have to try make my own script?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
       switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 37:
                console.log('left');
                $("#leftCollumn").show();
                $("#rightCollumn").hide();
                break;
            case 38:
                console.log('up');
                break;
            case 39:
                console.log('right');
                $("#leftCollumn").hide();
                $("#rightCollumn").show();
                break;
            case 40:
                console.log('down');
                break;
            default:
                console.log('all others');  
            }      
    });
```